# Help with the evaluation of an integral in Mathematica

Tags: symbolic

I have the following (m and n are integers)
$$ f[t] =\frac{ m^2n(n-1)}{2}t^2 \left(1 - (1 - t)^m \right)^{(n - 2)} (1 - t)^{(m - 1)} $$
$$
\text{Integrate}[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]$$
I also need the aymptotic case of the integral when m goes to infinity .Could somebody kindly help me this .Any help will be greatly appreciated .Presently I do not have access to Mathematica

Answer (score 1):

The result of your integral is

```
(m*n)/2 + Gamma[1 + n]*(-(Gamma[1/m]/Gamma[1/m + n]) + Gamma[2/m]/Gamma[2/m + n])
```

and the limit for m-> Infinity is 0

Edit:

use

```
Integrate[((m^2*n*(n - 1))/2)*t^2*(1 - (1 - t)^m)^(n - 2)*(1 - t)^(m - 1), t]
```

and insert the integration limits t->1 and t->0. Result is confirmed numerically.

Comment: @ Andreas could you kindly provide the code as well so that I can run it on wolfram cloud free account

Comment: fyi, limit t->0  seems to hang on V 12.2, or take longer time than I could wait.

Comment: @nasser just insert t=0